# Parameterize Parameter in API Body in dataflow

Tags: azure-data-factory

below is the image of the dynamic body in Web activity wherein I am leveraging a pipeline parameter

[image]
With the above set of configuration and values, the web activity is successfully getting executed.

Now for the same REST API, I am trying to use it as source in dataflow :

with the same aspect of configuration and it is failing with below error :

Dataflow param:
[image]

Error:
ailure to read most recent page request: DF-REST_001 - Error response from server: Some({"error":{"code":"DatasetExecuteQueriesError","pbi.error":{"code":"DatasetExecuteQueriesError","parameters":{},"details":[{"code":"DetailsMessage","detail":{"type":1,"value":"The JSON DDL request failed with the following error: Invalid JavaScript property identifier character: }. Path '', line 1, position 7.."}},{"code":"AnalysisServicesErrorCode","detail":{"type":1,"value":"3239182519"}}]}}}), Status code: 400. Please check your request url and body.

Can someone please help what I am doing Wrong?

Comment: Why do you need {} around $Query?  Is it not passing those to your API?

Comment: Are you able to successfully pass the body without any parameters? i.e., give body as `{"queries":[{"query":"EVALUATE VALUES(Date)"}],"serializerSettings":{"includeNulls":true}}`?

Comment: @SaideepArikontham, yes it is working without parameterizing.

Comment: Can you try to concat instead? like `'{"queries":[{"query":"'+$query+'"}],"serializerSettings":{"includeNulls":true}}` in the dataflow expression builder?

Comment: Hey @SaideepArikontham, I tried using concat and it worked. It means that string interpolation doesnt work in dataflows. but now there is another issue : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1068265/parsing-parameter-in-dataflow-issue.html

Comment: Converting it to an answer so it might help other community members. Regarding the other issue, you can try using this is expression builder: `'Evaluate SUMMARIZECOLUMNS( \'Date\'[DateDimId], \'Date\'[MonthNm], "CountRows",CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(\'Date\')))'`. This is [sample image](https://i.imgur.com/IInkBs7.png) for reference.

Comment: @SaideepArikontham : getting same error with this updated one

Comment: Hey @Nandan, I have defined the parameter value as in [this image](https://i.imgur.com/IUI5CkP.png). When I used this parameter to create a value, I got the output as in [this image](https://i.imgur.com/Y5YKQbd.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use dataflow parameter within the expression builder, we have to concatenate the parameter with our data. Look at the following demonstration.

- I am using derived column to show how to use parameters within expression builder. Using the dynamic content same as yours, I get the following output:

```
'{"queries":[{"query":"{$query}"}],"serializerSettings":{"includeNulls":true}}'
```

[image]

- String interpolation does not work in the dataflow expression builder. To get it correctly, you can concatenate the parameter using `+` to get desired result.

```
'{"queries":[{"query":"'+$query+'"}],"serializerSettings":{"includeNulls":true}}'
```

[image]

- Using the following content in expression builder also works (using `concat()` function).

```
concat('{"queries":[{"query":"',$query,'"}],"serializerSettings":{"includeNulls":true}}')
```